# Como enviar PDF para WebService - Asp .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-service

estou com problemas para enviar um PDF para um Web Service. No caso, a documentação está desta forma: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

então eu fiz o seguinte código:

```
private async void EnviarDocumentoWhats(string pdf)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://url");

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "token");

            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("remotejid", "ID"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("content", pdf),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("caption", "valor")
            });

            content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

            var result = await client.PostAsync("/message/document", content);

            string resultContent = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        }
    }
```

Ao rodar o aplicativo eu recebo o seguinte no resultcontent:

```
"{\"Code\":400,\"Type\":\"error\",\"Message\":\"Document title is empty, or wrong size.\"}\n"
```

Diz que o documento está vazio ou de tamanho errado, mas não sei como resolver está questão. Verificando novamente a documentação eu vi está parte:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém sabe como posso resolver esta situação? O erro como a própria mensagem diz é com relação a como este documento está sendo enviado, alguém tem uma sugestão ou dica do modo correto de enviar? Desde já agradeço quem puder ajudar.

Obs: O token e ID estão funcionando corretamente, já testei o envio apenas de mensagens utilizando outro método e está funcionando.

Comment: Aparentemente a API está esperando um `blob` ou `byte[]` convertido em `string` na propriedade content, assim como não há nenhuma indicação de que você deveria mudar o content-type no header...

Comment: @LeandroAngelo, Obrigado por responder. Olha, eu fiz alteração convertendo o documento para byte[] e depois para string, mas continua não dando certo, eu fiz a alteração na pergunta, você poderia dar uma olhada por favor? obrigado 
obs: o erro que da agora é esse : "{\"Code\":400,\"Type\":\"error\",\"Message\":\"error reading sent file\"}\n"

Comment: Você continua criando um multipart... a parte visível da sua documentação espera um post `application/json`... Faltam informações sobre essa especificação... onde está escrito que você deve converter o conteúdo em base64?

Comment: @LeandroAngelo, eu fiz outra modificação, não criei multipart. Esse método que coloquei agora é o mesmo que uso para enviar "somente texto", só adicionei um value a mais ao content, mas continua não funcionando, converti o documento para base64 e normal, mas continua dando erro.